# program throws CharConversionException in Java?

Tags: java

I am getting the below mentioned error in my catch block when i print using `e.printStackTrace();`This only occurs for few records when i read it from the DB2 database. So basically only few records throw the error rest work fine.

I have almost 1000 line of code and i am not sure were do i start from in order to understand/debug this error ? IS there any hint that i can get from the error message i should use to solve it ?

```
from the method getDataFromEMPHCForEmployeeDetails()----- com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][3.63.123] Caught java.io.CharConversionException.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:663)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:112)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ic.a(ic.java:2820)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ic.p(ic.java:521)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ic.N(ic.java:1558)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vn.e(vn.java:1147)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vn.getString(vn.java:1122)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vn.getString(vn.java:1698)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForEmployeeDetails(CreateChart.java:330)
    at CreateChart.iterateDirectReportNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:594)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForDirectReport(CreateChart.java:295)
    at CreateChart.iterateSecondLineManagerNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:562)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForSecondLine(CreateChart.java:251)
    at CreateChart.iterateThirdLineManagerNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:533)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForThirdLine(CreateChart.java:208)
    at CreateChart.iterateDirectorNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:506)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForDirector(CreateChart.java:168)
    at CreateChart.iterateVPNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:472)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForVp(CreateChart.java:126)
    at CreateChart.iterateFuncVPNamesFromArrayList(CreateChart.java:434)
    at CreateChart.getDataFromEMPHCForFuncVp(CreateChart.java:95)
    at CreateChart.main(CreateChart.java:613)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 186
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.t.a(t.java:19)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ic.a(ic.java:2816)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: sun.io.MalformedInputException
    at sun.io.ByteToCharUTF8.convert(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.t.a(t.java:16)
    ... 20 more
```

.

```
   public void getDataFromEMPHCForEmployeeDetails(String funcvp_name11, String vp_name11, String director_name11, String thirdline_name11, String secondline_name11, String directreport_name11){

        String myQuery11;
        if(directreport_name11 == ""){directreport_name11 = " AND DIRECT_REPORT IS NULL";}
        else{directreport_name11 =" AND DIRECT_REPORT ='"+ directreport_name11.replace("'", "''")+"'";}


        myQuery11 = "SELECT DISTINCT(SERIAL_NUM) FROM DB2INST1.EMP_HC  WHERE "+funcvp_name11+" "+vp_name11+" "+director_name11+" "+thirdline_name11+" "+ secondline_name11+""+directreport_name11;



        arraylistofEmployeeDetails = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
         resultSet = st.executeQuery(myQuery11);

        while (resultSet.next()) 
        { 
            String SERIAL_NUM = resultSet.getString("SERIAL_NUM"); 


            if(SERIAL_NUM == null){SERIAL_NUM="";}

            if (SERIAL_NUM.length() > 40){SERIAL_NUM = "Too Long";}
            arraylistofEmployeeDetails.add(SERIAL_NUM);
            System.out.println(SERIAL_NUM+"\n");

        }

        if(! (arraylistofEmployeeDetails.isEmpty())){
        writeEmployeeDetailsToJsonFile(arraylistofEmployeeDetails);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        StringWriter wtr = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pwtr = new PrintWriter(wtr);
        e.printStackTrace(pwtr);
        String stackTrace = wtr.toString();
        error_logs.append("from getDataFromEMPHCForEmployeeDetails()----- "+stackTrace+"\n");
    }
```

}

Comment: The exception is thrown in getDataFromEMPHCForEmployeeDetails(), so look for any character conversions there.

Comment: @GriffinG  one of the row returns this long string "This role is supporting the XX Information Management Data warehouse business wi
th a focus on XYZs Balanced Warehouse offering. The candidate should have a firm grasp of the underlying software compo" and this is one of the record that throws the above mentioned exception is there a limit on the number of characters allowed ?

Comment: @user3398326 are you trying to concat all this string in where clause?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a JVM parameter `-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3`, it solved the issue for me.

After setting the parameter `db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3`, an exception will not be thrown when a non-UTF8 character is encountered but rather it will be substituted by its equivalent Unicode replacement character.

See the IBM Support article for more details https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sqlexception-message-caught-javaiocharconversionexception-and-errorcode-4220

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with CharConversionException on DB2 jdbc driver with 1.8 Oracle Java with same error code, once updated to a never version it worked fine.

I downloaded [db2jcc_license_cu](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddb2jcclicensecu972jar.htm) and [db2jcc.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddb2jccjar.htm) from these links.

Maybe it is worth of trying.